# Calculate image cropping proportions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, crop

I have some cropping feature on my site.

[image]

So, the problem is that the real photo size is bigger that cropping area, and when i'm trying to get actual result of this cropping action i get proportions from visible - resized in css - area not from oryginal size of this image. How to calculate cropping proportion from resized to real size this image.

I do this but it's not working correctly, should i use some Math function or what, can anybody help?

```
var width = img.width;
var height = img.height;

// c.x, c.y, c.w, c.h is cropping coords which i recive from crop plugin callback function
// 360 is modal window size, resized area for displaying img

function showCoords(c) {
    cords_node = {
        "x": c.x ,
        "y": c.y,
        "width": width < c.w ? c.w : (width / 360) * c.w,
        "height": height < c.h ? c.w : (width / 360) * c.w
        /*x2: c.x2,
        y2: c.y2*/
    };
    return cords_node;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find out the ratio of change:

```
// find the ratio of change in H and W...
var ratioW = $('.image')[0].naturalWidth / $('.image').width();
var ratioH = $('.image')[0].naturalHeight / $('.image').height();
var ratio = Math.min(ratioW, ratioH);
// now.. multiply all your coords by 'ratio'
// ...
```